# How to color edges of a graph which has multiple edges connecting certain vertices

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm studying [BIBD(Balanced Incomplete Block Design)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design) and want to draw some graphs by coloring their blocks in different colors, respectively. A block is a collection of edges (or vertices).

For example, (10,4,2)-BIBD, with blocks

```
{{0,1,2,3},{0,1,4,5},{0,2,4,6},{0,3,7,8},{0,5,7,9},{0,6,8,9},
 {1,2,7,8},{1,3,6,9},{1,4,7,9},{1,5,6,8},{2,3,5,9},{2,4,8,9},
 {2,5,6,7},{3,4,5,8},{3,4,6,7}}
```

can be drawn by

```
GraphPlot[{0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 0 -> 1, 1 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 0 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 
           4 -> 6, 0 -> 3, 3 -> 7, 7 -> 9, 0 -> 6, 6 -> 8, 8 -> 9, 1 -> 2, 
           2 -> 7, 7 -> 8, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 6, 6 -> 9, 1 -> 4, 4 -> 7, 7 -> 9, 
           1 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 8, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 5, 5 -> 9, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 8, 
           8 -> 9, 2 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 7, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 8, 3 -> 4, 
           4 -> 6, 6 -> 7}, 
  Method -> "CircularEmbedding", 
  BaselinePosition -> Top, 
  VertexLabeling -> True, 
  MultiedgeStyle -> 0.04]
```

[image]

(This example is from the text book *Combinatorial Design - Stinson*).

I want to draw each block in its own individual color. How do I do that?

Comment: I deleted my answer because it didn't solve your problem and because I don't think that it is possible to colour two edges between the same two vertices differently *using `Graph` in Mathematica 10*.  The the new-in-10 multigraph support is not the way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It seems that the following doesn't work on *v9*. It does work on *v8* and *v10*.

Here is what I propose based on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4501/1356):

```
rule = {0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 0 -> 1, 1 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 0 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 6, 0 -> 3, 
        3 -> 7, 7 -> 9, 0 -> 6, 6 -> 8, 8 -> 9, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 7, 7 -> 8, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 6, 
        6 -> 9, 1 -> 4, 4 -> 7, 7 -> 9, 1 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 8, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 5, 5 -> 9, 
        2 -> 4, 4 -> 8, 8 -> 9, 2 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 7, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 8, 3 -> 4, 
        4 -> 6, 6 -> 7};
blocks = {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {0, 1, 4, 5}, {0, 2, 4, 6}, {0, 3, 7, 8}, {0, 5, 7, 9}, 
          {0, 6, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 7, 8}, {1, 3, 6, 9}, {1, 4, 7, 9}, {1, 5, 6, 8}, 
          {2, 3, 5, 9}, {2, 4, 8, 9}, {2, 5, 6, 7}, {3, 4, 5, 8}, {3, 4, 6, 7}};
coloredRule = Select[Flatten[
    Thread[{Rule @@@ Subsets[blocks[[#]], {2}], 
        ConstantArray[#, 6]}] & /@ Range@Length@blocks, 1], MemberQ[rule, First@#] &];
col = Flatten[{#, {#2, Line[foo]}} & @@@ 
        Thread[{Range@Length@blocks, 
        RGBColor /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {Length@blocks, 3}]}] /. foo -> #1, 1];
GraphPlot[coloredRule, ImagePadding -> 10, 
  EdgeRenderingFunction -> (Function@Switch[Slot@3, foo] /. foo -> Sequence @@ Evaluate@col), 
  VertexLabeling -> True, 
  Method -> "CircularEmbedding"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

<strike>Of course, the doubled edges are coloured twice, so the last colour applied remains.</strike> I was wrong, the edges in that example are doubled, with two different colours.

The following produces the right number of edges:

```
grule = GatherBy[Gather[rule], Length];
singledColoredRule = Delete[coloredRule, List /@ Last /@ Table[Flatten@
       Position[MemberQ[grule[[2, i]], First@#] & /@ coloredRule, 
        True], {i, Length@grule[[2]]}]];
SeedRandom@4;
colours = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {Length@blocks, 3}];
col = Flatten[{#, {#2, Line[foo]}} & @@@ 
     Thread[{Range@Length@blocks, RGBColor /@ colours}] /. foo -> #1, 1];
g[size_] := GraphPlot[singledColoredRule, 
   EdgeRenderingFunction -> (Function@Switch[Slot@3, foo] /. foo -> Sequence @@ Evaluate@col), VertexLabeling -> True, 
   Method -> "CircularEmbedding", ImageSize -> size];

label = 
  Grid[Partition[Graphics[{RGBColor@#, Rectangle[], White, Text[#2, {0.5, 0.5}]}] & @@@
     Thread@{colours, StringJoin /@ Map[ToString, blocks, {2}]}, 3, 3, 1, {}], 
     Spacings -> {-1, -1}, ItemSize -> {Scaled@.05, 0}];
Row@{g@350, label}
```

[image]

Of course, now one edge belonging to two different blocks will only take the colour of the latest block.

Comment: @GuineaPig I know.. :) I fixed this but didn't update the answer .. :) I was trying to make the edge dashed with two different colours.. :) Or fading from one to an other with `VertexColors` but I've failed so far.

Comment: @GuineaPig Better now :D

Comment: @GuineaPig `foo` is anything you like. It's just a variable that I replace so it doesn't appear in the function. It wouldn't work if it was appearing there. Since I am using `#1` or `#2` I just need to trick _Matematica_ by doing `Something[foo, #1, #2]&@@@{somelists}/.foo->#1` in order to have the correct syntax (in the first case `Line[#1]).`

Comment: @GuineaPig If I was using `Something[Line[#1], #1, #2]&@@@{somelists}` the expression inside of `Line` would be replaced by values of `somelists` while it needs to stand as `#1` so `EdgeRenderingFunction` works.

Comment: I have one more question. How do I choose each color, not randomly? I think I should change `colours`... but don't know how to do it. Your code is marvelous but it's very hard to interpret for me. Some colors between adjacent blocks are similar, so it's quite hard to recognize them distinctly. For example, check the blocks `{0,2,4,6}` and `{2489}`, or `{0,5,7,9}` and `{2,3,5,9}`.

Comment: @GuineaPig Just create the list you want with the colours you want, as long as the length of your lists are equal (`Length@col === Length@blocks)`.

Comment: Ok. I've figured it out. :)

Comment: Oh no... I've found another error in your answer. It is that the `colours` in your code produces some duplicated edges. For instance, for a block `{0,1,2,3}`, it labels `{{0 -> 1, 1},{1 -> 2, 1},{1 -> 3, 1},{2 -> 3, 1}}` like this. It should be fixed as `{{0 -> 1, 1},{1 -> 2, 1},{2 -> 3, 1}}`. I'm working out. Seems like easy to fix.

Comment: Oh wait, seems like the `singledColoredRule` in your code is intended to delete those duplicated edges. But I think it isn't doing it's job properly D:

Comment: @GuineaPig I'm afraid that I don't see the error there :) Why should `{1->3,1}` be deleted? I delete `{1->3,8}` already :)

Comment: @GuineaPig Since `Length@singledColoredRule === Length@rule` there is the right number of edges, nothing more should be deleted :)

Comment: Check the edges between the vertices `{0,1,2,3}`. They should linked as one closed line, but they are comprising a [complete graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) of $K_4$.

Comment: Ok. I've tried to fix it but looks hard to me, so I tried manual fix. And here is a [result](http://i.imgur.com/kbfylPF.png?1).

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand then, by block `{0,1,2,3}` what exactly are you expecting for a cycle?

Comment: Apparently not `Subsets[{0,1,2,3},{2}]`.

Comment: @GuineaPig What you want is `coloredRule = Sort@Select[
    Flatten[Thread[{Rule @@@ Delete[Thread@{#, RotateLeft@#} &@blocks[[#]], -1], ConstantArray[#, 3]}] & /@ Range@Length@blocks, 1], MemberQ[rule, First@#] &];` then use `GraphPlot[coloredRule ...]`. That should give you the same list as `edges` on your image.

Answer (score 3):

```
 blocks = {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {0, 1, 4, 5}, {0, 2, 4, 6}, {0, 3, 7, 8}, 
           {0, 5, 7, 9}, {0, 6, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 7, 8}, {1, 3, 6, 9},
           {1, 4, 7, 9}, {1, 5, 6, 8}, {2, 3, 5, 9}, {2, 4, 8, 9}, 
           {2, 5, 6, 7}, {3, 4, 5, 8}, {3, 4, 6, 7}};
edglst = {0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 0 -> 1, 1 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 0 -> 2, 
          2 -> 4, 4 -> 6, 0 -> 3, 3 -> 7, 7 -> 9, 0 -> 6, 6 -> 8, 8 -> 9, 
          1 -> 2, 2 -> 7, 7 -> 8, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 6, 6 -> 9, 1 -> 4, 4 -> 7, 
          7 -> 9, 1 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 8, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 5, 5 -> 9, 2 -> 4, 
          4 -> 8, 8 -> 9, 2 -> 5, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 7, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 8, 
          3 -> 4, 4 -> 6, 6 -> 7};
```

The following trick works in Version 9 if the number of edges between a pair of vertices is at most 2:

```
edglst2 = Join @@ (Tally[edglst] /. 
           {Rule[a_, b_], 2} :> {Rule[a, b], Rule[b, a]} /. {x_Rule, 1} :> {x});
vopts = {VertexStyle -> LightYellow, VertexSize -> 0.20, 
         VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", {1/2, 1/2}], 
         VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[20, Red, Bold, Italic]};

gg = Graph[edglst2, vopts, GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", 
           VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> 500, 
           EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", BaseStyle -> Thick];
gg2 = HighlightGraph[gg, (EdgeList[Subgraph[gg, #]] & /@ blocks), 
                     ImageSize -> 500, BaseStyle -> Thick];
Row[{gg, gg2}]
```

[image]

To "mimic" the edge directions in the original graph, one can use `EdgeShapeFunction` as follows:

```
eS = Property[DirectedEdge[#, #2], EdgeShapeFunction -> 
       GraphElementData[{"FilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> #3, "ArrowPositions" -> #4}]] &;

edglstb = Join @@ (Tally[edglst] /. {Rule[a_, b_], 2} :> 
                                     {esf[a, b, .03, .9], esf[b, a, -.03, .1]} /. 
                                 {Rule[a_, b_], 1} :> {esf[a, b, .03, .98]});
ggb = Graph[edglstb, vopts,GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", VertexLabels -> "Name",
            ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> 500, BaseStyle -> Thick];
ggb2 = HighlightGraph[ggb, EdgeList[Subgraph[ggb, #]] & /@ blocks, 
                      ImageSize -> 500, BaseStyle -> Thick];
Row[{ggb, ggb2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Once again (and again and again) +1 :)

Comment: Thank you @Öskå -- and, once again, I like your answer better as it works more generally.

Comment: My answer is not correct as it stands right now, I need to fix the fact that some edges are doubled while they shouldn't (e.g. `0->3`). Two edges with different colours shouldn't be doubled, like it is on your example. Mine gives two different edges with two different colours, I need to fix this :)

Comment: My question is that I want to color blocks in different colors. For example, a block {0, 1, 2, 3} must has different color compared to {0, 1, 4, 5}. But in your answer, two edges {0,1} has same color.