# Graph: Coloring parallel edges individually

Tags: graphs-and-networks, color, style

**CODE:**

```
Graph[{Style[0 -> 1, Red], Style[0 -> 1, {Blue, Dashed}]}]
```

[image]

This Mathematica code will make both lines solid Red, since they belong to the same two vertices and have the same direction.

> I want one of them to be red, the other blue dashed for instance. How can I do this?

Comment: Why is this solution not working for you ? [`(4501)`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4501/coloring-edges-in-graphplot)

Comment: Both lines end up being red!

Comment: Did you try adapting it to your case, not just copy-pasting it ?

Comment: Yes well I wrote a script to generate these things. But I realise that once you set the style for the line from 0->1, then it can not change. I looked into the mathematica examples on their website, but all of them are very simple and give no hint as to how this problem can be solved...

Answer (score 13):

**Update 3:** With the new-in-version-12.1 function [`EdgeTaggedGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeTaggedGraph.html) we can style and label edges individually in multi-graphs:

```
labels = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
edges = {a -> b, a -> b, a -> b, a -> b, a -> e, e -> b};
styles = {Red, Directive[Dashed, Blue], Orange, 
   Directive[Purple, Dashing[.01]],  Green, Green};

labelededges = MapThread[Style[Labeled[#, #2], #3] &, {edges, labels, styles}] ;

EdgeTaggedGraph[labelededges, EdgeLabels -> "Name", 
 ImageSize -> Medium, BaseStyle -> Thick, EdgeLabelStyle -> 16, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> 16, PlotTheme -> "DiagramGold"]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** A much more convenient approach to construct a custom `EdgeShapeFunction` to style multi-edges individually:

```
styles = Association[PropertyValue[g1, EdgeStyle]] ;
esf = {Dashing[{}], First[styles[#2] = RotateRight[styles[#2]]], 
   Arrowheads[Large], Arrow[#, .1]} &;
Graph[g1, EdgeShapeFunction -> esf]
```

[image]

**Update:** To make it more convenient  *to specify precisely the color (style) of each edge in a multigraph, not resort to a fixed sequence of styles* as suggested by @David G Stork in the comments:

Specify edge labels for each edge using `EdgeStyle`:

```
g1 = Graph[{a -> b, a -> b, a -> b, a -> b, a -> c, a -> c, a -> c, c  -> b}, 
VertexLabelStyle -> 18, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", GraphStyle -> "DiagramGold",
EdgeStyle -> {(a -> b) -> {Red, Directive[Dashed, Blue], Orange, 
 Directive[Purple, Dashing[.01]]},
 (a -> c) -> {Green, Cyan, Yellow}, (c -> b) -> {Pink}}];
```

In `g1` multi-edges are colored with a single color.

Extract the styles for desired edge (*e*) into the variable `style[e]`, and initialize the variable `index[e]` to 1.

```
ClearAll[index, style]
distinctedges = DeleteDuplicates[EdgeList[g1]];
(style[#] = PropertyValue[{g1, #}, EdgeStyle])& /@ distinctedges;
(index[#] = 1) & /@  distinctedges;
```

Inject the multiple styles for each edge using `EdgeShapeFunction`:

```
g2 = Fold[(SetProperty[{#,  #2}, EdgeShapeFunction -> 
  ({Arrowheads[Large], Thick, style[#2][[index[#2]++]], Arrow[#, .1]} &)]) &, 
   g1,  distinctedges];

Row[{g1, g2}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can use `EdgeShapeFunction`:

```
styles={Red, Directive[Dashed, Blue], Orange, Directive[Purple, Dashing[.01]], 
        Green, Green};
i = 1; 
Graph[{a -> b, a -> b, a -> b, a -> b, a -> e, e -> b},  
EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Arrowheads[Large],Thick,styles[[i++]],Arrow@#} &),
VertexLabels->"Name"]
```

[image]

If you have at most two edges between a pair of vertices, you can also *cheat* using the `Arrowheads` option:

```
Graph[{Style[0 -> 1, {Arrowheads[.04], Red}], Style[1 -> 0,
   {Blue, Arrowheads[{-.04, 0.}], Dashed}], 0 -> 2, 2 -> 1},
 VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much !

Comment: @johanCarlstrom, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: This isn't QUITE what I need.  I want to be able to specify precisely the color (style) of each edge in a multigraph, not resort to a fixed sequence of styles (as given by @kglr.  How do I do that?

Comment: Can we trust that the EdgeShapeFunction is applied in a consistent order, so that if I give a list of styles in the same order as EdgeList, they will consistently be applied to the corresponding edges? I think you had an answer which solved this but not sure which one ... Motivation: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199541/12

Comment: @Szabolcs, I am not sure in which order `EdgeShapeFunction` processes multiple edges.

Comment: Do you have access to the desktop version of M12.1? If yes, it would be really useful for me if you could give IGraph/M a bit of a testing with the new edge tagged graphs.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I am still using v11.3 on desktop. It will be a few months before I can get desktop v12.1.