# How to specify different colors for edges going between the same two vertices in Graph?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

Here is an example:

```
edge1 = Property[1 -> 2, EdgeStyle -> Red];
edge2 = Property[1 -> 2, EdgeStyle -> Blue];

Graph[{edge1, edge2}]
```

[image: Example]

This does not work the way I want it. How can I make it so that I get two edges, one blue and one red?

Comment: Please post actual code in addition to pictures, so people can copy/paste your code and play with it.

Comment: If one edge is directed and another not, there's no problem:  `Graph[{1, 2}, {Property[1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, EdgeStyle -> Red], 
  Property[1 <-> 2, EdgeStyle -> Blue]}]`

Comment: Hmm, is there a way around this sacrifice? :D

Comment: I'm no expert of graph theory and its representation in *Mathematica*, but it seems to me that you are trying to specify two colors *for the same edge* of that graph, not for two different ones. David's suggestion works because now the graph has two *different* edges, one directed, and one undirected.

Comment: duplicate: [Graph - Coloring parallel edges individually](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84477/125)

Answer (score 4):

Another trick you can do:

```
Graph[Join[Table[1 -> 2, {10}], Table[2 -> 3, {5}], 
  Table[3 -> 1, {5}]],
 EdgeShapeFunction -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] 
     2 -> (a = 0; {a++; ColorData[35, "ColorList"][[a]],
       Arrow[#]} &), 
   2 \[DirectedEdge] 
     3 -> (b = 0; {b++; ColorData[55, "ColorList"][[b]],
       Arrow[#]} &), 
   3 \[DirectedEdge] 1 -> (c = 0; {c++; ColorData[5, "ColorList"][[c]],
       Arrow[#]} &)}]
```

[image]

Comment: halmir's solution preserves the class of edge so that appropriate graph analysis functions work, e.g., `VertexInDegree[g]` yields $\{5, 10, 5\}$.  *+1*.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to render both a directed and an undirected edge with the same arrow `EdgeShapeFunction`.  Alas, the full graph representation will retain the different classes of edge, so functions such as `FindKClan`, `VertexOutDegree`, `VertexInDegree`, and others that distinguish between different classes of edge will give incorrect answers.

```
  Graph[{1, 2}, 
     {Property[1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, EdgeStyle -> Red], 
      Property[1 <-> 2, EdgeStyle -> Blue]}, 
    EdgeShapeFunction -> (Arrow[#] &)]
```

[image]

Because there are only two classes of edge (directed and undirected), following this approach also implies that one can have at most two edges between a given pair of vertexes.

You can kludge together a graph representation that appears as if three (or more) edges join two vertexes by forcing different vertexes to lie in the same position, through `VertexCoordinates`:

```
Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {Property[1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, EdgeStyle -> Red], 
  Property[1 <-> 2, EdgeStyle -> Blue], 
  Property[1 <-> 3, EdgeStyle -> Green]}, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> (Arrow[#] &), 
 VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Although the funny-looking `(Arrow[#]&)` works, I think that more properly you would want `(Arrow[#1]&)` for your `EdgeShapeFunction`, to reming the reader that [a custom edge function is passed a sequence of two arguments](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeShapeFunction.html): 1) a list of points describing the edge; 2) the edge denomination itself. `Arrow` needs only the first one. I think this is also the reason why simply using `Arrow` doesn't work: the edge definition would be interpreted as an arrow setback amount, which is expected to be a number.

Comment: I had originally defined an `EdgeShapeFunction` of the form `ef[#, ___]` and called it within `Graph`, as the two-argument approach would seem to require.  I found indeed that both `(Arrow[#]&)` and `(Arrow[#1]&)` worked, but don't know why the former does.

Comment: I think `(Arrow[#]&)` works because `#` always represents only the first argument provided to the function, i.e. it is automatically equivalent to `#1`, so that call discards the second argument passed to `Arrow` by `EdgeShapeFunction`. In other words, `(Arrow[#]&)` is equivalent to `Arrow[#1]&`; both are different from `(Arrow)` alone, which would behave as `(Arrow[__]&)`, i.e. `SlotSequence[]`. That's why I suggested using `#1` rather than `#`: although they are perfectly equivalent, the latter makes the intended behavior more explicit.

Comment: @becko Did you not see my three-edge solution posted yesterday?

Comment: I see it now. This edit was not visible to me before. Deleting comments.