# Weighted graph with multiple different coloured non-weighted paths - styling

Tags: graphs-and-networks, color, style, object-oriented

This follows on from my previous question answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183066/adding-overlapping-non-weighted-directed-edges-to-a-weighted-undirected-graph).

Ultimately, I now have a graph which I've simplified for posting here:

```
g1 = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}, EdgeWeight -> {10, 10, 10},
  VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Placed[i, Center], {i, 3}], 
  VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[White, Bold, 15], VertexSize -> 0.1, 
  GraphLayout -> {"VertexLayout" -> {"SpringElectricalEmbedding", 
      "EdgeWeighted" -> True}}]

r0 = {1, 2, 3};
e0 = DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[r0, 2, 1];

r1 = {1, 2, 1};
e1 = DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[r1, 2, 1];

g2 = SetProperty[EdgeAdd[g1, Join[
    e0, e1
    ]], {VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g1], 
   VertexStyle -> {1 -> Red}, EdgeStyle -> {
     Alternatives @@ e0 -> {Green, Thick}, 
     Alternatives @@ e1 -> {Blue, Thick}
     }}]
```

Which outputs the following:

[image: Example Graph]

Ideally, one of the arrows from `v1` to `v2` would be green. However, as Mathematica views this edge in `e1` as the same as the equivalent edge in `e0`, the formatting of the latter defined edge overwrites the `e0` edge.

Research into options so far has spanned: (1) using [this EdgeShapeFunction technique](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84477/graph-coloring-parallel-edges-individually), which is not working as I believe the syntax isn't handling the collection of edges correctly and (2) looking into [constructing custom sub DirectedEdge type objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/once-more-on-object-orientation-in-mathematica-does-it-have-to-be-so-hard) to trick Mathematica into thinking they were different, which I don't believe is possible given my layman's understanding of the software.

Comment: Properties for multigraphs are not supported. This is a very annoying limitation of Mathematica. I suggest you contact Wolfram Support and complain about it. If you (and others) don't, then there is no chance that this will improve in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the same approach as in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84481/125)

```
i = 1;
SetProperty[EdgeAdd[g1, Join[e0, e1]], 
 {VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g1],  VertexStyle -> {1 -> Red}, 
  EdgeShapeFunction->{Alternatives @@ Intersection[e0, e1] -> 
    ({Arrowheads[{0, 0, .05, 0}], Thick, {Blue, Green}[[i++]], Arrow[#]} &)},
  EdgeStyle -> {Alternatives@@e1 -> {Blue, Thick}, Alternatives@@e0 -> {Green, Thick}}}]
```

[image]

For the general case with multiple groups with arbitrary intersections, you can use the general method in the linked answer by specifying the list of styles for each distinct edge in the input graph ... as follows:

```
ClearAll[index, style]
styles = Normal @ GroupBy[Flatten[Thread[# -> 
   Directive[#2, Arrowheads[{0, 0, .05, 0}], Thick]] & @@@ 
      Thread[{{e0, e1}, {Green, Blue}}]], First -> Last] ;
g0 = Graph[Join[EdgeList[g1], e0, e1], EdgeStyle -> styles, VertexStyle -> {1 -> Red} , 
   VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Placed[i, Center], {i, 3}], 
   VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[White, Bold, 15], 
   VertexSize -> 0.1  , VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g1]] ;
distinctedges = DeleteDuplicates[Join[e0, e1]] ;
(style[#] = PropertyValue[{g0, #}, EdgeStyle]) & /@ distinctedges;
(index[#] = 1) & /@  distinctedges;
g2 = Fold[(SetProperty[{#,  #2}, EdgeShapeFunction -> 
     ({ style[#2][[index[#2]++]], Arrow[#]} &)]) &,   g0,  distinctedges]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In general, here's another way to style multigraph edges without using `SetProperty`. Just make a matrix of the edges and their styles:

```
$styles = {{a -> e, Green}, {e -> b, Green}, {a -> b, Red}, 
           {a -> b, Directive[Dashing[{Small, Small}], Blue]}, {a -> b, RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0]}, 
           {a -> b, Directive[RGBColor[0.5, 0, 0.5], Dashing[0.01`]]}};

ef = (Block[{st, p}, st = $styles[[p = 
          FirstPosition[$styles, #2 | (#2 /. DirectedEdge -> Rule)][[1]]]][[2]];
          $styles = Delete[$styles, p]; 
          {Thickness[0.008], Arrowheads[{{.08, .5}}], st, Arrow@#}] &)

Graph[$styles[[All,1]], 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> 0.14, 
  VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 17, FontColor -> White], 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> ef
]
```

[image]

Here's your example:

```
u = Directive[Gray, Thickness[0.002], Arrowheads[0]];
$styles = {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1], 
   1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0], 
   1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2 -> u, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> u, 
   2 \[DirectedEdge] 3 -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0], 
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> u, 
   2 \[DirectedEdge] 1 -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1]};
Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
  3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 
  2 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3}, 
 EdgeWeight -> {10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
 VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Placed[i, Center], {i, 3}], 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[White, Bold, 15], VertexSize -> 0.1, 
 VertexStyle -> {1 -> Red}, 
 GraphLayout -> {"VertexLayout" -> {"SpringElectricalEmbedding", 
 "EdgeWeighted" -> True}}, EdgeShapeFunction -> (
   Module[{st, p},
 st = $styles[[p = 
          FirstPosition[$styles, #2][[1]]]][[2]]; $styles = 
      Delete[$styles, p];
     {Arrowheads[{{.03, .95}}], st, Arrow@#}] &), 
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Comment: I am unsure how I am able to discern different routes via this method, sorry? On a map with 12 nodes, and five routes of length 5-10, this is quite mentally cumbersome.

Comment: @JordanMacLachlan it's easy to just specify the styles explicitly

Comment: I haven't seen this way of doing multigraph styling, nice!

Comment: @JordanMacLachlan Do you see how it works now?

Comment: @M.R - yes, I do, thank you. Quite a clever way of going about it. I'm not going to pretend I understand the Mathematica syntax 100%, but I get the gist.

Comment: For the record: if I could note two posts as answers to the original question, I would also accept this solution. Given I implemented the technique first posted, I will keep that as my accepted answer, however. Regardless, I really appreciate your help. Thank you.