# GraphUnion but with multiple edges?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have two graphs `G1` and `G2` with the same vertex set. I would like to take the union of `G1` and `G2 in` such a way that if both `G1` and `G2` contain the same edge, then the union inherits both of those edges, labeled appropriately. Unfortunately, `GraphUnion[G1, G2]` seems to lump common edges into one. How can I accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 7):

**Update:** If `EdgeStyle` and `EdgeLabels` for multi-edges are  given as lists, we can use the option `EdgeShapeFunction` to label and style each edge individually:

```
graphSum = Module[{esf, styles = GroupBy[Flatten[PropertyValue[#, EdgeStyle] & /@ {##}], 
       First -> Last, Flatten],
     labels = GroupBy[Flatten[PropertyValue[#, EdgeLabels] & /@ {##}], 
       First -> Last, Flatten]},
    esf = {Dashing[{}], Text[First[labels[#2] = RotateRight[labels[#2] ]], 
        BSplineFunction[#][1/2]], 
       First[styles[#2] = RotateRight[styles[#2] ]], Arrow[#]} &;
    GraphComputation`GraphSum[##, VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeShapeFunction -> esf]] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
ga = Graph[{1 -> 2}, EdgeStyle -> {_ :> Red}, 
   EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Style[{e, "ga"}, 16, Black, Bold]}];
gb = Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 2, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}, 
   EdgeStyle -> {_ :> Green , (1 -> 2) -> {Blue, Orange, Magenta}}, 
   EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Style[{e, "gb"}, 16, Black, Bold], (1 -> 2) ->
      Array[Style[{#, DirectedEdge[1, 2], "gb"}, 16, Black, Bold]&, 3]}] ; 
SetProperty[graphSum[ga, gb], ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

```
SetProperty[graphSum[ga, ga, ga, gb, gb], 
 {ImageSize -> 800, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  VertexShape -> Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], FaceForm[LightBlue], 
     Disk[{0, 0}, Offset[8]]}], AspectRatio -> 1/3}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

`` GraphComputation`GraphSum `` gives the desired result:

```
g1 = Graph[{1 -> 2}];
g2 = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}];
GraphComputation`GraphSum[g1, g2, VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeLabels -> "Name" ]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
ga = RandomGraph[{5, 7}, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  ImageSize -> 300];
gb = RandomGraph[{10, 10},  DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name",
  ImageSize -> 300];
Row[{ga, gb, HighlightGraph[GraphComputation`GraphSum[ga, gb, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
    ImageSize -> 500 ], {ga, gb}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you have precisely the same vertices in precisely the same order (i.e. `VertexList[g1] === VertexList[g2]`), then you can just add the adjacency matrices.

```
g1 = Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 <-> 2}]
```

[image]

```
g2 = Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3}]
```

[image]

```
AdjacencyGraph[VertexList[g1], AdjacencyMatrix[g1] + AdjacencyMatrix[g2]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, join the edge lists. If you do this, it does not matter if the vertex lists are ordered the same. They just need to contain the same vertices.

```
Graph[VertexList[g1], Join[EdgeList[g1], EdgeList[g2]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent. Is it possible to label the edges in the new graph according to which graph they came from? I.e. to inherit the edge labels that were already assigned in g1 and g2?

Comment: @theQman It's quite problematic. Unfortunately, Mathematica does not properly support multigraph properties.  It doesn't even say that it doesn't support them, things just go wrong. The one exception is edge weights, which you could "abuse" for this purpose if you wanted to.

Comment: @theQman [Here's one discussion of the issue.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92014/12). If you care about multigraphs, I suggest you contact Wolfram Support and ask them to add this feature. The only chance for it to happen is if *many* people ask for it (to prove that there really is a demand).

Comment: Thank you. How about edge coloring? Is it possible to have color the edges according to which graph they came from, instead of using labels?

Comment: @theQman The only properties that *sort of* work are EdgeWeight, EdgeCapacity and EdgeCost. None of the rest do, not even EdgeStyle. There are tricks that can be used to display parallel edges with different colours but they are hacky and inconvenient. You will find many questions about this, e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84477/12