# Combining two directed graphs without loosing any edge

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have two directed graphs given below:

```
one={1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1};
two={1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4};
```

I simply want to map the two graphs as a single graph keeping all the edges repeated as `multiple edges` like 1->2, 1->3. I tried

```
GraphUnion[one, two]
```

but it is not giving me what I am after. I want to keep all the edges in these two graphs and differentiate the two graphs with different colors.

Any idea?

Example 2

```
one = {1 \[DirectedEdge] 10, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 6,
6 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
6 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 7, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 
6 \[DirectedEdge] 11, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 12, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 13, 
6 \[DirectedEdge] 14, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 15, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 16, 
6 \[DirectedEdge] 17, 11 \[DirectedEdge] 9};    

two = {1 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 
4 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 
7 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 8 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 9 \[DirectedEdge] 8, 
10 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 11 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 12 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 
13 \[DirectedEdge] 9, 14 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 15 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 
16 \[DirectedEdge] 6, 17 \[DirectedEdge] 6};

HighlightGraph[EdgeAdd[Graph[one, VertexLabels -> "Name"], two], two, 
VertexLabels -> "Name"]
GraphUnion[one, two, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

In `Highlight` there is something wrong because there are two edges like `11->9`, and only one of them should be RED, the other be BLUE. It seems that identical edges are assumed to belong to graph `two` only. What I am after is to separate them with different colors as the colors have a meaning in the context.
`GraphUnion` is not generating the same graph at all because it takes mathematical union of the two graphs, eliminating the repeated edges.

I simply want to map two separate graphs with different colors on top of each other without loosing any directed edge.

Comment: `Graph@Join[one, two]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`EdgeAdd`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeAdd.html):

```
EdgeAdd[one, two, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `` GraphComputation`GraphSum ``:

```
GraphComputation`GraphSum[Graph @ one, Graph @ two, VertexLabels->"Name"]
```

> same picture

`GraphUnion` works as expected (that is, it will not the give desired output): it takes the `Union` of vertices and the `Union` of edges from the two input graphs:

[`GraphUnion -> Details and Options`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphUnion.html):

- The graph union Graph[$v_1, e_1$] ⋃ Graph[$v_2, e_2$] is given by Graph[$v_1$ ⋃ $v_2$, $e_1$ ⋃  $e_2$].

Comment: It works but somehow I cannot highlight the second graph correctly. I will edit the question with a different example. By the way, `GraphUnion` is not giving the desired output. You might want to look at my edition to the question.

Comment: `GraphComputationGraphSum[Graph @ one, Graph @ two, VertexLabels->"Name"]` works fine but I need to differentiate the two graphs with different colors.

Comment: @Tugrul, Unfortunately, individual styling and labeling of multi-edges is a non-trivial task in mathematica. You can use [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201210/125).  See also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184185/125), [and this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84481/125),

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance and help. I will look into the links you sent me.