# Coloring multi-edges in graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks, color, style

I have the following edgelist and colors:

```
edges = {0 <-> 1, 0 <-> 2, 0 <-> 1, 2 <-> 1, 0 <-> 1};
colors = {Blue, Red, Red, Yellow, Green};
```

But I can't find a way to color the edges using these colors. My first try of course was to use something like:

```
Graph[edges, EdgeStyle -> {0 <-> 1 -> Blue,  0 <-> 2 -> Red, 0 <-> 1 -> Red, 
  2 <-> 1 -> Yellow, 0 <-> 1 -> Green}]
```

But in this all of the edges between 0 and 1 turn out to be green even though only one of them should be. I also tried to do this with

```
colors = {Blue, Red, Red, Yellow, Green};
i = 1;
Graph[{0 <-> 1, 0 <-> 2,  0 <-> 1, 2 <-> 1,  0 <-> 1}, 
EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Arrowheads[Large], Thick, colors[[i++]], 
 Arrow @ #} &)]
```

But now a wrong edge gets the green color for some reason. Any ideas? I already looked into [Graph: Coloring parallel edges individually](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84477/graph-coloring-parallel-edges-individually) which didn't help me with this really.

Comment: Mathematica does not properly support edge properties for multigraphs. It is not possible to assign a separate EdgeStyle property to different edges that run between the same vertices. If you care about this functionality, you should contact [Wolfram Support](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/) and request it. I believe they will only fix this if many people request it.

Comment: @Szabolcs Really? That's a shame for me at least.

Comment: See here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92014/12 EdgeWeight, EdgeCapacity and EdgeCost are the only properties that work for multigraphs (if you're careful). Unfortunately, this limitation is not properly documented, things just fail ... However, development of Graph has just picked up again (there was a recent Twitch streams about it), so it's the best time to request this feature again. If you believe you need this, please do write to Wolfram Support and request it.

Comment: @Szabolcs Sure, will do! But couldn't I go around it then and define different weights or costs to edges and then color them according to the weight/cost? Or will it still fail?

Comment: The issue is that `EdgeStyle` cannot be used. Since Mathematica refers to edges by their endpoints, there is no way to distinguish between parallel edges, and assign different properties to them. Colouring is normally done through EdgeStyle. That won't work here. Thus any solution one might come up with will be inconvenient and error-prone.

Comment: The solution I was aware of, and the one you also found, was to define a new EdgeRenderingFunction, and colour edges with different colours on the 1st, 2nd, etc. calls of this function. However, as you just discovered, the EdgeRenderingFunction is not called in the same order as edges appear in `EdgeList`. I guess you could record the order in which edges are rendered, then reorder the `colors` vector based on that. But this is hackish and error prone again.

Comment: EdgeWeight, etc. won't help here because it can't colour things. Only EdgeStyle (or EdgeRenderingFunction) can colour things. Mathematica has no built-in feature to directly map an EdgeWeight into an EdgeStyle in some way. My IGraph/M package does have such a feature, but it will protect you by detecting multigraphs and reporting an error. Obviously, I can't implement a robust mapping between edge properties on a multigraph until Wolfram starts supporting these properly.

Comment: @Szabolcs Oh, I see. Anyways your comments have been useful as I think I learned important things about Mathematica once again.

Comment: I hope you're not scared away from Mathematica's Graph for good. Do check out [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) if  you work with graphs. Feel free to email me with any feedback.

Comment: @Szabolcs Any tips how you can record the order in EdgeRenderingFunction? This would be useful also in other cases than hacking this thing.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have been using it in multiple occasions but this is the first time I'm really having any issues (as this is the first project I need multigraphs for). So don't fear, not leaving it for good :)

Comment: The edge rendering function takes the edge name as its 2nd argument. You can `Sow` it, then `Reap` it. You get an edge list this way. Now find a permutation that transforms this edge list to the EdgeList of the graph (or vice versa). This can be done with `Ordering`. Note that `Ordering` can also be used to invert a permutation—this will be useful for this task.

Comment: @Szabolcs I made it work, thank you. However as you said it's error prone. Still as I only needed a visualization of one specific graph it's good for that.

Answer (score 5):

```
edges = {0 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 0 \[UndirectedEdge] 2,  
  0 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 1,  0 \[UndirectedEdge] 1};
colors = {Blue, Red, Red, Yellow, Green};
styles = GroupBy[Thread[edges -> colors], First -> Last]
```

[image]

```
esf = {First[styles[#2] = RotateRight[styles[#2]]], Arrow[#]} &;

Graph[edges, EdgeStyle -> Normal[styles], EdgeShapeFunction -> esf, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeLabels -> "Name" ]
```

[image]

**Update:** In version 12.1 you can use [`EdgeTaggedGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeTaggedGraph.html) to have individual styles and labels for multi-edges:

```
stylededges = MapThread[Style, {edges, colors}];
EdgeTaggedGraph[stylededges, EdgeLabels -> "Name" ]
```

[image]