# How to get distinct labels on parallel edges in a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

The following doesn't display as you'd expect:

```
Graph[{Labeled[1 -> 2, "A"], Labeled[1 -> 2, "B"]}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

The parallel edges are both labeled "A". Is this a bug or is it a design feature? The definition of `EdgeLabels` suggests that Mathematica expects an edge to be identifiable by its ends(!)

In fact, `FullForm` shows that it gets converted to

```
{{1, 2}, {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2}, {EdgeLabels -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> "A"}, VertexLabels -> {"Name"}}}
```

Ugh!

**Anyone have any ideas how to get distinct labels to display on parallel edges?**

Specifically, I use a simple data format for my digraphs. For the example above, it would be

```
{{1,{{"A",2},{"B",2}}}}
```

though in general there's an entry in the outermost list for each source vertex, and the vertices and labels are a variety of things.

Is there some (relatively easy) way (using `EdgeShapeFunction` perhaps) of creating a `Graph` that displays correctly?

Comment: This *has* to be a bug, yes? Why would it ever make sense to label both edges "A" when you specifically request otherwise?

Comment: Report was submitted to Wolfram Technical Support [CASE:4276060]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GraphUnion but with multiple edges?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184160/graphunion-but-with-multiple-edges)

Comment: @user6014 It's not a bug, it's a limitation of the API. Edges are referred to by their endpoints, therefore parallel edges are not distinguishable.  I suggest you (and also David Bevan) contact Wolfram and ask for this to be addressed. I suspect I'm the only one who keeps complaining about this again and again and they assume no one else really needs/wants this to work ...

Comment: Please see here and comments: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92014/12

Comment: @Szabolcs that's incredibly frustrating. I would imagine this "limitation" pretty quickly gets in the way of many real world use cases for `Graph`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update 2:** With version 12.1 comes [`EdgeTaggedGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeTaggedGraph.html) which enables individual labeling and styling multi-edges:

```
EdgeTaggedGraph[{Style[Labeled[1 <-> 2, "lbl1"], Red], 
    Style[Labeled[1 <-> 2, "lbl2"], Blue], 2 <-> 3,   2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, 
   EdgeLabels->Placed["Name", Center]]
```

[image]

**Update:** An alternative method that that takes lists of  vertices, edges, edge labels and edge styles.

Lexicographic sorting of the edges, labels and styles based on the vertex list seem to match the order in which edges are processed for rendering.

```
ClearAll[multiGraph2]
multiGraph2[vl_, elist_, elabels_, estyles_, o : OptionsPattern[Graph]] := 
 Module[{esf, edges, labels, styles, 
   sorted = Transpose@ SortBy[Transpose[{elist, elabels,  estyles}], 
     {PositionIndex[vl]@#[[1, 1]] &, PositionIndex[vl]@#[[1, 2]] &}]},
  {edges, labels, styles} = {sorted[[1]], ## & @@ (RotateRight /@ sorted[[2 ;;]])};
  esf = {First[styles = RotateLeft[styles]], 
     GraphElementData["Arrow"][##] /. Arrowheads[ah_] :>
        Arrowheads[Append[ah, {.05, .5, Graphics[
          Text[Framed[First[labels = RotateLeft[labels]], 
             FrameStyle -> None, Background -> White]]]}]]} &;
  Graph[vl, edges, EdgeShapeFunction -> esf, o]]
```

**Example:**

```
SeedRandom[12345]
edges = RandomSample@ EdgeList[RandomGraph[{7, 10}, 
     DirectedEdges -> True]][[{1, 1, 2, 2,  2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}]];
edges = Flatten@Gather[edges];
styles = ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@edges];
labels = Flatten[MapIndexed[Row[{#, CharacterRange["A", "Z"][[#2[[1]]]]}, "-"] &, #] & /@ 
    Gather[edges]];

multiGraph2[RandomSample[Range[7]], edges, labels, styles, 
 VertexSize -> Medium, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

A function that  produces a multi-graph with distinct labels and styles for multi-edges given an input list of the form

```
{{v1, {{v11, label11, style11}, {v12, label12, style12}, ...}, ...}
```

The list is processed into an edge list and `Association`s for edge labels and styles that are used to construct a custom `EdgeShapeFunction`:

```
ClearAll[multiGraph]
multiGraph[a_, o : OptionsPattern[Graph]] := Module[{esf, 
  edges = Flatten[Thread[DirectedEdge[#[[1]], #[[2, All, 1]]]] & /@ a], 
  edgelabels = GroupBy[#, First -> Last, Flatten] &@
     Flatten[Thread[Thread[DirectedEdge[#[[1]], #[[2, All, 1]]]] -> #[[2, All, 2]]]& /@ a],
  edgestyles = GroupBy[#, First -> Last, Flatten] &@
     Flatten[Thread[Thread[DirectedEdge[#[[1]], #[[2, All, 1]]]] -> #[[2, All, 3]]]& /@ a]},
  esf = {Dashing[{}], First[edgestyles[#2] = RotateRight[edgestyles[#2] ]],
   GraphElementData["Arrow"][##] /. Arrowheads[ah_] :> Arrowheads[Append[ah, {.05, .5, 
     Graphics[Text[Framed[First[edgelabels[#2] = RotateRight[edgelabels[#2] ]], 
      FrameStyle -> None, Background -> White]]]}]]} &;
Graph[edges, EdgeShapeFunction -> esf, o]]
```

**Examples:**

```
data = {{1, {{2, "A", Red}, {2, "B", Blue}, {3, "C", Green}, 
        {3, "D", Directive[Thick, Orange]}}},
     {2, {{3, "E", Directive[Dashed, Thick, Purple]}, {1, "F", Gray}}}};

data2 = data /. s_String :> Style[RandomWord["Noun"], 16, Black];
multiGraph[data2, VertexSize -> Small, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], ImageSize -> Large, VertexLabelStyle -> Large]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[7777]
randomdata = {#, Table[{RandomChoice[Range@4], Style[RandomWord["Noun"], 14], 
       Opacity[1, RandomColor[]]}, RandomInteger[{2, 4}]]} & /@ Range[4];
multiGraph[randomdata, VertexSize -> Small,  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
 ImageSize -> Large, VertexLabelStyle -> Medium]
```

[image]

See also:

- [GraphUnion but with multiple edges?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184160/graphunion-but-with-multiple-edges)
- [Graph: Coloring parallel edges
  individually](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84477/125)
- [Weighted graph with multiple different coloured non-weighted paths -
  styling](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/183086/125)
- [Coloring multi-edges in
  graphs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/184216/125)

Comment: Thanks for having wrapped this up into a reusable function!

Comment: @Szabolcs, after using `Print[#2]` in edge shape function with many random graphs it seems that edges are processed in an order that depends on the ordering of the vertex list. I posted an alternative approach that uses this observation.

Answer (score 1):

**THIS IS AN EXTENDED COMMENT RATHER THAN AN ANSWER.**

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)
```

Using [`Labeled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html) the first label instance is used for both edges.

```
Graph[
 {Labeled[1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, "A"], Labeled[1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, "B"]},
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

However, using [`VertexLabels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexLabels.html) the second label instance is used for both edges.

```
Graph[
 {1 -> 2, 1 -> 2},
 VertexLabels -> "Name",
 EdgeLabels -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> "A", 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> "B"}]
```

[image]

Either approach results in a wrong label and both are bugs.

**EDIT:** Report was submitted to Wolfram Technical Support [CASE:4276060]

Comment: Not a bug, but a (severe) limitation of the API. Which edge does `1->2` refer to? There's no way to tell. This can only be fixed by changing the API so that edges become distinguishable (e.g. they're referred to by their index, or an additional key, rather than just their end vertices). Given the slow progress on `Graph` recently, and the major overhaul that would be needed to fix this, I do not have much hope ... But I also think that this is the single most frustrating limitation of `Graph` ....

Comment: Styling is the smallest issue, more generally it's not possible to use properties with multigraphs. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92014/12