# Explanation required for the Slot function

Tags: slot

I have been trying to understand the following function

```
l = {{1, 3}, {3, 4}};
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 1 -> 2, 3 -> 4}, 
 VertexLabeling -> True, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> (If[
     Intersection[l, {#2}] != {}, {Red, Arrow[#1, .1]}, {Blue, 
      Arrow[#1, .1]}] &)]
```

(Courtesy of the link: [Coloring edges in GraphPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4501/coloring-edges-in-graphplot)).

I am unable to understand how the slot function is working..i.e., how Intersection[l,{#2}] is working out.

Could someone please explain this

Thanks

Comment: Have you already read the [Pure Functions tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) and the parameters of `EdgeRenderingFunction` listed in the [`GraphPlot` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphPlot.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get insight into what the arguments for `EdgeRenderingFunction` are by "looking under the hood",e.g.

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 3 -> 4, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 1 -> 2, 3 -> 4}, 
 VertexLabeling -> True, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> (If[Intersection[l, {#2}] != {}, 
     Print[{#1, #2, #3}]; {Red, Arrow[#1, .1]}, {Blue, 
      Arrow[#1, .1]}] &)]
```

You will slot 1 (#1) are the coordinates of the edge ends, #2 is the vertex pair, and the third slot is any label specified for edge (in this case).

So the code aims to color  edges {1,3},{3,4} blue (non-empty intersection with `l`) or red (disjoint with `l`).